# How to convert text field input to integer in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
fun Add() {
    var num1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var num2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Arrangement.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = num1,
            onValueChange = { num1 = it })
        TextField (value = num2, onValueChange = { num2 = it })
    }
    remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val sum = num1 + num2
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxsize(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            Toast.maketext(
                context,
                "result:$sum",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }) { Text("output") }
    }
}
```

I'm getting output as concatenated values eg: 5 + 5 = 55 but I need out put as 5 + 5 = 10 sum of numbers.

Comment: No, I tried that but it dint worked for me

Comment: That's exactly the same as the answer you accepted (use `.toInt()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use use `num1.toInt()` and `num2.toInt()` to add the numbers up.

Answer (score 1):

This is no different than any other string to number conversion, instead of

```
val sum = num1 + num2
```

do

```
val sum = (num1.toInt() + num2.toInt()).toString()
```

Comment: I implemented this method but app crashed . In logcat I get error as "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main"

Comment: You have to check the input before converting to an integer to ensure it is formatted correctly, my answer is just the starting point, you always need to validate input.